# Umbraco Lucene.Net.Index.MergePolicy.MergeException What is causing this?

Tags: umbraco, lucene.net, lucene

I am using Umbraco and for some reason out of the blue I get the Visual Studio JIT Debugger popup asking me if I want to debug and exception with w3wp.exe, I attached to it and found the following exception, I can't find any cause for this as I haven't added anything new.

```
Lucene.Net.Index.MergePolicy.MergeException was unhandled
  Message=Exception of type 'Lucene.Net.Index.MergePolicy+MergeException' was thrown.
  Source=Lucene.Net
  StackTrace:
       at Lucene.Net.Index.ConcurrentMergeScheduler.HandleMergeException(Exception exc)
       at Lucene.Net.Index.ConcurrentMergeScheduler.MergeThread.Run()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException: Lucene.Net.Index.CorruptIndexException
       Message=doc counts differ for segment _3qw: fieldsReader shows 1025 but segmentInfo shows 1
       Source=Lucene.Net
       StackTrace:
            at Lucene.Net.Index.IndexWriter.HandleMergeException(Exception t, OneMerge merge)
            at Lucene.Net.Index.IndexWriter.Merge(OneMerge merge)
            at Lucene.Net.Index.ConcurrentMergeScheduler.DoMerge(OneMerge merge)
            at Lucene.Net.Index.ConcurrentMergeScheduler.MergeThread.Run()
       InnerException:
```

Does anyone have any idea what is causing this or how to fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer from this link:

http://our.umbraco.org/forum/ourumb-dev-forum/bugs/16066-Missing-LuceneNet-assembly

on Dunfee posted this reply 6 months ago
Just went through a migration from one location to another.  I removed the contents of App_Data/TEMP/ExamineIndexes and after a minute or so of watching the browser spinner (while the Lucene cache was being rebuilt) the site came up.